# Instructions in a Custom Offline Payment not showing

Tags: magento2.2, custom, payment-methods

I am building a custom offline payment for magento 2.2.2

After a week working on this I gave up and I am asking for help.
The extension works fine the only problem I have is to be able to display the instructions in the frontend, as the Bank Transfer Payment has.

Here you can see my code.
https://github.com/techbertu/Offline_Payment

I really appreciate the help on this, since I am going crazy on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing your template file which is referenced in
https://github.com/techbertu/Offline_Payment/blob/master/view/frontend/web/js/view/payment/method-renderer/offlinepayment-method.js

Look at the code of the module-offline-payments like you described. They are all using a template from module-offline-payments/web/template/payment/...

so you would need to have the same path replicated in your module at https://github.com/techbertu/Offline_Payment/tree/master/view/frontend/web

---

This template files are responsible for displaying the content of the payment method if you select the payment method in the checkout.
F.e. the template for the banktransfer method located in:
`magento/module-offline-payments/view/frontend/web/template/payment/banktransfer.html`

is responsible for rendering the instructions by:

```
<p data-bind="html: getInstructions()"></p>
```

---

*edit for comment:

I guess the remaining problem is that the value in `window.checkoutConfig.payment.instructions[this.item.method];` for your payment method is missing. Maybe try this out by testing the `getInstructions` method of your method-renderer just with a hardcoded string to be sure about that.

But what you will need to do to fix this is adding configProviders to provide the new config to `window.checkoutConfig`.
Please reference to `vendor/magento/module-offline-payments/etc/frontend/di.xml` where the config providers are added for the module-offline-payments.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I had the template file but for some reason, it wasn't uploaded on GitHub. I have updated now - of course still with the original problem.

Comment: edited my post according to your comment

Comment: I have added the file Offline_Payment/etc/frontend/di.xml and Offline_Payment/Model/Payment/InstructionsConfigProvider.php, I am still not working, I am almost sure that there is something wrong in InstructionsConfigProvider.php

Comment: there are several things not ideal. First: class Offline is not defined in https://github.com/techbertu/Offline_Payment/blob/master/Model/Payment/InstructionsConfigProvider.php. You need to provide your own payment method code there.
Also keep care that you do not overwrite the default stuff in https://github.com/techbertu/Offline_Payment/blob/master/etc/frontend/di.xml. Give your item an unique name, otherwise you will overwrite the item from the module-offline-payment. Also you do not need the item with the name "offline_payment_checkmo_config_provider" there.

Comment: I really appreciate your help on this. This is the first extension that I am building so I am a beginner.

How do I provide my own payment method code, in InstructionsConfigProvider.php?

I have changed the name of the item in di.xml and removed  "offline_payment_checkmo_config_provider".

Comment: just like it is done in the module-offline-payments. In your payment class you have a const defined like: `const PAYMENT_METHOD_BANKTRANSFER_CODE = 'checkmo';`. And in your configprovider you reference this const by `Banktransfer::PAYMENT_METHOD_BANKTRANSFER_CODE`.
dont forget to replace the banktransfer class and const names by yours.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your help, the payment method work with the instructions showing. Thanks again I could not have done it without you.